# Font Awesome Pseudo element to Bootstrap card-top-img(img tag)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, pseudo-element

I'd like to put [a Font Awesome font](https://fontawesome.com/icons/file-alt?style=solid) to the upper image section of bootstrap card component, `card-img-top`.

Following similar with [the official guide](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js) and [some solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757661/replace-img-tag-with-font-awesome-icon-from-css), it didn't work:

```
// card-img.css
<script>
  FontAwesomeConfig = { searchPseudoElements: true };
</script>

.card-top-img {
  display: none;
}

.card-head::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";
  content: "\f15c";
}
```

---

```
    <!-- list.html (I'm do in Django project) -->
    <div class="row">
      {% for resume in resume_list %}
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
          <!-- add for pseudo element -->
          <div class="card-head">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h5 class="card-title text-success">
          </div>
          ...
```

But it just render small empty box:

[image]

How can I work this?

Comment: That rather looks like you did not properly embed the font file to begin with ...

Comment: Here is a perfect solution that uses `card-block`: https://www.codeply.com/go/T0SPcWuyBL/bootstrap-4-row-of-cards-with-icons

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the following link in your head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Or, if you are using Font Awesome version 5, you need to include this in the head section of your HTML document:

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: Omitted including link in the layout template. (`<script defer src="{% static 'fontawesome-5/fontawesome-all.js' %}"></script>`) I'm using a dowloaded file.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48638482/8270343 to see why using CDNs can make your websites/apps load much faster!

Comment: Even it is another matter, a helpful thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You not put  **font awesome** `class` file

```
   <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
```

try this

```
<div class="card-head">
         <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
          </div>
```

and you need to put in your header

```
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

try to read guidance https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css

Comment: It seemed not a pseudo element.

`div.card-head` is  I made for that, not the bootstrap's class.